# Getting Error while importing the project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

When I import the project **Automation_Project_Template** with external dependencies I get the following error message:

> 'C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.3.1/selenium-firefox-driver-3.3.1.jar'
>   in project 'Automation_Project_Template' cannot be read or is not a
>   valid ZIP file

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

unzip the whole package copy the project file and paste at the default location where the projects are build.Then try to import .

Answer (score 0):

Delete it from your local repository and try again. It will be loaded again from the remote repository. I have checked the driver version 3.3.1 and it works for me. If it fails again for you, check where it is loaded from and post the repository here.